# Añadir "Embedded Timeline" de Twitter en C#

Tags: c#, html

Al crear un embed desde `publish.twitter.com` me ha dado este código HTML, el cual quiero pasarlo a C#, la pregunta es, como declaro las variables? Que debo hacer?

Es decir, quiero que en un Form aparezca el Timeline de Twitter de una Página, como puedo añadir-lo mediante el código que me han dado de HTML a C#?

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="220" data-height="200" data-theme="dark" data-link-color="#E95F28" href="https://twitter.com/PÁGINA">
    Tweets by PÁGINA
</a> 
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8">
</script>
```

Comment: No estoy entendiendo la pregunta (creo) ¿pretendes pasar un código HTML a C#? o ¿Pretendes mostrar el contenido de una página web en un control?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Pretendo poner el código HTML en C# se que es posible, pero no sé como, es decir se que con oEmbed API puedo conseguir el resultado pero necesito ayuda.

Comment: Me tendrás que disculpar, pero sigo sin entenderte :( por "*Poner el código HTML en C#*" ¿te refieres a que usando C# se vea el contenido de ese HTML? Si es así, Te refieres a que ¿Teniendo una aplicación de escritorio quieres mostrar el contenido de ese HTML en un formulario?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Quiero que en un Form salga el timeline de twitter de una página, es decir, que se muestre como en el html que he puesto arriba, no sé si me expreso correctamente.

Comment: Ahora si te entendí :) ¿podrías editar la pregunta para expresar esto también (por favor)?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster listo, si me pudieses ayudar, me sería de gran útilidad, gracias!

Comment: Ojalá yo tuviera la respuesta, pero voy a ver si encuentro a alguien que pueda responderte :) (¿Has probado usar un [WebView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView)?)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Sí, lo he pensado, pero no creo que fuese la solución más profesional.

Comment: @OhhLiberr y a que te refieres con solucion profesional?? un webview es suficientemente profesional para mostrar una pagina web (o una seccion de ella)...

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que deseas es mostrar contenido web en un formulario puedes usar el control WebBrowser aun que yo te sugiero el [GeckoWebBrowser](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/).

Para la segunda opcion puedes crear una pagina que se llame mypage.html e insertar el codigo ese, luego lo inicializas de esta manera:

```
if(!Xpcom.IsInitialized) Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");
_GeckoWebBrowser _brs = new GeckoWebBrowser() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
_brs.Navigate("mypage.html");
_brs.AddMessageEventListener("myFunction", recived);
_brs.DomClick += _brs_DomClick;
_brs.DocumentCompleted += _brs_DocumentCompleted;
```

Se requiere DocumentComplete para realizar cualquier accion, puedes capturar los clicks y las funciones javascript.

```
    void _brs_DocumentCompleted(object sender, Gecko.Events.GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        //change dom by class
        injecthtm("navbar-brand", "Mi brand");

    }
    bool injecthtm(string clase, string value)
    {
        var ele = _brs.Document.GetElementsByClassName(clase);
        bool ret = false;
        foreach (GeckoHtmlElement elem in ele)
        {
            elem.InnerHtml = value;
            ret = true;
        }
        return ret;
    }
    void _brs_DomClick(object sender, DomMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //Capture dom click.
    }
    void recived(string s)
    {
        //mymunction from javascript
    }
```